# Convert jquery solution angular directive

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs

I am new to angularjs and when ever i am faced with a problem like DOM manipulation etc, i turn towards jquery. I know its bad programming and i want to stop doing this. I tried a few tutorials out there to learn more about directives and I found some good ones, but none of them explained or gave examples on how to solve real world problems.

Now i have come up with Solution to add a floating button that stops at footer when scrolled. I basicaly change the button style from `position:fixed` to `poisition:absolute`

I would like to convert this solution to angular directive. How can i do that?

Here is the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/KOEKJjYiXMubEWqjbYut?p=preview

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question as well, not only at an external location.